# Tasks deployed to custom Mesos role waiting forever

Tags: mesos, mesosphere

I'm trying to deploy marathon-lb to a Mesos role that I have created on a public agent in my cluster. My custom role is visible in the cluster, but when marathon-lb is deployed to my role, it ends up waiting forever.

I'm not handy enough with Mesos to figure out what the deployment is waiting for. I've looked at the master/agent logs but nothing jumps out as relevant. Any pointers in this regard are appreciated.

The masters are not configured to whitelist any specific roles (via `--roles`), so I should be able to introduce arbitrary roles to the cluster. Indeed, masters can see the `"slave_public_tools"` role:

```
[centos@ip-10-0-1-25 ~]$ curl -s master.mesos:5050/roles | jq
{
  "roles": [
    {
      "frameworks": [
        "2a2b67f7-1440-4594-9cb9-bb86d3cbc110-0002",
        "2a2b67f7-1440-4594-9cb9-bb86d3cbc110-0001"
      ],
      "name": "*",
      "resources": {
        "cpus": 0,
        "disk": 0,
        "gpus": 0,
        "mem": 0
      },
      "weight": 1
    },
    {
      "frameworks": [
        "2a2b67f7-1440-4594-9cb9-bb86d3cbc110-0000"
      ],
      "name": "slave_public",
      "resources": {
        "cpus": 0,
        "disk": 0,
        "gpus": 0,
        "mem": 0
      },
      "weight": 1
    },
    {
      "frameworks": [
        "2a2b67f7-1440-4594-9cb9-bb86d3cbc110-0004",
        "2a2b67f7-1440-4594-9cb9-bb86d3cbc110-0003"
      ],
      "name": "slave_public_tools",
      "resources": {
        "cpus": 0,
        "disk": 0,
        "gpus": 0,
        "mem": 0
      },
      "weight": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

In case it matters, I created the `"slave_public_tools"` role by setting `MESOS_DEFAULT_ROLE=slave_public_tools` in `/var/lib/dcos/mesos-slave-common` on a public agent before the agent is started for the first time. The mesos agent seems to recognize the default role setting, and the role has resources:

```
[centos@ip-10-0-1-25 ~]$ url -s 10.0.1.14:5051/state | jq '{ default_role : .flags.default_role }, .reserved_resources_full'
{
  "default_role": "slave_public_tools"
}
{
  "slave_public_tools": [
    {
      "name": "ports",
      "type": "RANGES",
      "ranges": {
        "range": [
          {
            "begin": 1,
            "end": 21
          },
          {
            "begin": 23,
            "end": 5050
          },
          {
            "begin": 5052,
            "end": 32000
          }
        ]
      },
      "role": "slave_public_tools"
    },
    {
      "name": "disk",
      "type": "SCALAR",
      "scalar": {
        "value": 51042
      },
      "role": "slave_public_tools",
      "disk": {
        "source": {
          "type": "MOUNT",
          "mount": {
            "root": "/dcos/volume0"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "disk",
      "type": "SCALAR",
      "scalar": {
        "value": 51042
      },
      "role": "slave_public_tools"
    },
    {
      "name": "cpus",
      "type": "SCALAR",
      "scalar": {
        "value": 2
      },
      "role": "slave_public_tools"
    },
    {
      "name": "mem",
      "type": "SCALAR",
      "scalar": {
        "value": 6037
      },
      "role": "slave_public_tools"
    }
  ]
}
```

I use the following options.json when deploying marathon-lb:

```
{
  "marathon-lb":{
    "name":"marathon-lb-tools",
    "haproxy-group":"public-tools",
    "bind-http-https":true,
    "role":"slave_public_tools"
  }
}
```

By the way I'm doing this because I want to two marathon-lb deployments in my cluster. Both of the LBs need to be externally accessible, but one will proxy a high-throughput application and will need to scale accordingly, and the other will be used for various low-bandwidth apps.

Maybe there's a better way to achieve these goals, but creating a separate Mesos role that is available to a marathon-lb configured with a specific haproxy group seemed obvious to me.

Comment: If you run this a two different agents, you could use hostname constraints to pin the Marathon-lb instances to specific agents

Comment: Do you have logs form scheduler? There should be information why task is not started.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for your suggestions. I learned that my marathon-lb was not deploying because the marathon cluster that dc/os runs by default only accept offers from the '*' and 'slave_public' roles.

I needed to start another marathon instance with `mesos_role` set to "slave_public_tools" to make this work.